# treenode's treeview property. How is this set?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm designing custom TreeNodes at the moment and have come up with a bit of a mystery.

TreeNode's TreeView property is a public property that can be used to get the TreeView the TreeNode belongs to. What I can't seem to find is how is this set.

I assume that it is set by the TreeNodeCollection when you call one of it's Add methods though I can't find how the TreeView control passes a reference to itself to the TreeNode through the collection. Is there an undocumented method being used or something else. Or mabey I missing the bleeding obvious again, I am known for doing that.

Thanks for any help
Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TreeNode](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/WinForms/Managed/System/WinForms/TreeNode@cs/1/TreeNode@cs) contains an internal constructor that looks like this:

```
internal TreeNode(TreeView treeView) : this()
{
    this.treeView = treeView;
}
```

It is called by the [TreeView object](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/wpf/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TreeView@cs/1305600/TreeView@cs) to create a root node:

```
root = new TreeNode(this);
```

And of course, if the `treeView` member is not set, it will be set the first time you try to retrieve it from the property:

```
public TreeView TreeView {
    get {
        if (treeView == null)
            treeView = FindTreeView();
        return treeView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, does this mean that when you Add a TreeNode to a collection it gets recreated so this constructor can be called?

Comment: Presumably, the constructor is called by some other class in the same assembly, for performance reasons (setting it means that the recursive FindTreeView() is not required to be called).

Answer (score 0):

As per the source code, an internal method `FindTreeView` is used to recursively get the parent of a given `TreeNode`. You can take a look at the source [here](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/WinForms/Managed/System/WinForms/TreeNode@cs/1/TreeNode@cs)

```
public TreeView TreeView {
        get {
            if (treeView == null)
                treeView = FindTreeView();
            return treeView;
        }
    }
```

Note: Snippet above is from the source link posted above.

Additionally, as Robert Harvey has explained in his answer, it can also be set through an internal constructor:

```
internal TreeNode(TreeView treeView) : this() {
        this.treeView = treeView;
    }
```

Comment: True, but `treeView` can also be set by an internal constructor. See my answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey True. Should I edit my answer to include this info, or remove it outright?